# Spring Integration Aggregator failing - "No reply received within timeout" message being displayed

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am building a Proof of Concept showcasing the end-to-end flow of an XML-based RESTful application built with Spring Integration, the overall idea being the following:

1) A HTTP Inbound Gateway that accepts incoming requests from the calling client

2) A set of @Router, @ServiceActivator, @Splitter & @Aggregator artifacts to process the incoming request and send a set of possible responses (the response XSD has optional elements inside a parent element that get populated based on the use-case) back to the calling client

I tested the flow on a local Tomcat 7.0.68 instance using Chrome's Advanced REST client extension and it always works fine the 1st time and that's the end of it.

Every test thereafter fails in the exact same way - after the final invocation of the @CorrelationStrategy method in the Aggregator, the flow ends with just this message, "No reply received within timeout".

The docs (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#http-timeout) say that for an HTTP Inbound Gateway, both the timeout properties default to 1000ms. I actually did try to manually set reply-timeout to 50000 but it didn't work.

Also, http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#aggregator-config says,
"The timeout interval to wait when sending a reply Message to the output-channel or discard-channel. Defaults to -1 - blocking indefinitely"

Since the failure seems to do with Spring Integration relying on some default timeout, can someone please let me know if there is anything else to try from my side?

Here are the most relevant pieces of code from my project:

Context file: **product-integration.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd ">

<int:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.amb.splitteraggregator"/>

<!-- POST -->
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="gatewayProductRequests"
    reply-channel="gatewayProductResponses"
    supported-methods="POST" 
    path="/product"
    request-payload-type="java.lang.Stringe>

    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/xml" produces="application/xml"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:channel id="gatewayProductResponses" />
<int:channel id="validatedProductRequests" />
<int:channel id="upstreamProductResponses" />
<int:channel id="downStreamProductRequests" />
<int:channel id="downStreamRawProductsAndRequest" />
<int:channel id="downStreamProductRequestBatches" />
<int:channel id="compositeMessagesWithResponse" />
<int:channel id="compositeMessagesForAggregation" />
<int:channel id="compositeMessagesWithRawProductsAndRequestOrResponse" />
```

Aggregator: **ProductAggregator.java**

```
@MessageEndpoint 
public class ProductAggregator {
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProductAggregator.class);

@Autowired
ProductServiceHelper productServiceHelper;

@Aggregator(inputChannel="compositeMessagesForAggregation", outputChannel="upstreamProductResponses", sendTimeout="10000")
public Message<Composite> generateAggregatedResponse(List<Message<Composite>> listOfCompositeMessagesForAggregation) {
    logger.info("generateAggregatedResponse :: START");

    PRODUCTRESPONSE productResponse = new PRODUCTRESPONSE();
    PRODUCTRESPONSEDATA productResponseData = new PRODUCTRESPONSEDATA();
    ERROR error = new ERROR();

    PRODUCTRESPONSE productResponseInComposite = null;
    List<PRODUCT> listOfProductsInComposite = null;

    List<PRODUCT> listOfProductsToReturn = new ArrayList<PRODUCT>();
    StringBuilder errorsToReturn = new StringBuilder();

    String uuid = null;

    for(Message<Composite> compositeMessage : listOfCompositeMessagesForAggregation) {
        productResponseInComposite = compositeMessage.getPayload().getProductResponse();
        if (null != productResponseInComposite.getPRODUCTRESPONSEDATA()) {
            uuid = productResponseInComposite.getPRODUCTRESPONSEDATA().getUuid();
            listOfProductsInComposite = productResponseInComposite.getPRODUCTRESPONSEDATA().getPRODUCT();
            listOfProductsToReturn.addAll(listOfProductsInComposite);
        } else if (null != productResponseInComposite.getERROR()) {
            errorsToReturn.append(productResponseInComposite.getERROR().getErrorMsgCode());
            errorsToReturn.append(",");
        }
    }

    if (null != listOfProductsToReturn && !listOfProductsToReturn.isEmpty()) {
        productResponseData.getPRODUCT().addAll(listOfProductsToReturn);
        productResponseData.setUuid(uuid);
        productResponse.setPRODUCTRESPONSEDATA(productResponseData);
    }

    if (errorsToReturn.length() != 0) {
        error.setErrorMsgCode(errorsToReturn.toString());
        error.setUuid(uuid);
        productResponse.setERROR(error);
    }

    Composite compositeWithAggregatedResponse = productServiceHelper.buildComposite(false, productResponse);
    Message<Composite> compositeMessageWithAggregatedResponse = MessageBuilder.withPayload(compositeWithAggregatedResponse).build();

    logger.info("generateAggregatedResponse :: END");
    return compositeMessageWithAggregatedResponse;
}

@CorrelationStrategy
public UUID correlateByUUID(Message<Composite> compositeMessageForAggregation) {
    logger.info("correlateByUUID :: START");
    logger.info("Correlation by UUID done");
    logger.info("correlateByUUID :: END");
    UUID correlationUUID = null;

    if (null != compositeMessageForAggregation.getPayload().getProductResponse().getPRODUCTRESPONSEDATA()) {
        correlationUUID = UUID.fromString(compositeMessageForAggregation.getPayload().getProductResponse().getPRODUCTRESPONSEDATA().getUuid());
    } else if (null != compositeMessageForAggregation.getPayload().getProductResponse().getERROR()) {
        correlationUUID = UUID.fromString(compositeMessageForAggregation.getPayload().getProductResponse().getERROR().getUuid());
    }
    return correlationUUID;
}
```

}

Custom composite object moving through the channels: **Composite.java**

```
public class Composite {
private PRODUCTREQUEST productRequest;
private PRODUCTRESPONSE productResponse;
private List<RawProduct> listOfRawProducts;
private boolean isError;

public Composite(boolean isError, PRODUCTREQUEST productRequest) {
    this.isError = isError;
    this.productRequest = productRequest;
}

public Composite(boolean isError, PRODUCTRESPONSE productResponse) {
    this.isError = isError;
    this.productResponse = productResponse;
}

public Composite(boolean isError, List<RawProduct> listOfRawProducts) {
    this.isError = isError;
    this.listOfRawProducts = new ArrayList<RawProduct>(listOfRawProducts);
}

public Composite(boolean isError, PRODUCTREQUEST productRequest, List<RawProduct> listOfRawProducts) {
    this.isError = isError;
    this.productRequest = productRequest;
    this.listOfRawProducts = new ArrayList<RawProduct>(listOfRawProducts);
}

public PRODUCTREQUEST getProductRequest() {
    return productRequest;
}

public PRODUCTRESPONSE getProductResponse() {
    return productResponse;
}

public boolean isError() {
    return isError;
}

public List<RawProduct> getListOfRawProducts() {
    return this.listOfRawProducts;
}
```

}

**pom.xml**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.amb</groupId>
<artifactId>splitteraggregator</artifactId>
<name>SpringWebSplitterAggregator</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.3.7.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <spring.integration.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Integration Stream -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
        <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
    </dependency>       

    <!-- Spring Integration HTTP -->    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.integration.version}</version>
    </dependency>       

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please let me know if more code snippets from my project are required - this is my first question on Stack Overflow so pardon me if there is any etiquette that I missed.

-
Bharath

Comment: " and send a set of possible responses back to the calling client". That isn't possible. There can only be one reply for one response. The `TemporaryReplyChannel` is used once. You should reconsider your vision on the matter.

Comment: And DEBUG logging is always your friend - follow the messages through the flow to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Please, switch on DEBUG for the `org.springframework.integration` category and investigate logs what's going on. You show to a lot of channels, but there is only one aggregator component presented...

Comment: @ArtemBilan - Thanks Artem, I edited my question - I actually meant to say that response XML has optional sub-elements inside the root and the business case decides what (sub-elements) to populate. So yes, it is finally only one response for one request

Comment: OK. Makes sense. Thanks. Well, actually I don't see `reply-timeout` option on your `int-http:inbound-gateway`. BTW, how about to share StackTrace for that `new MessageTimeoutException("No reply received within timeout")` on the matter?

Comment: The DEBUG helped quite a bit in making me figure out what might be  happening but there are still some missing pieces in my head. Basically, in my use case, the XML Schema mandates that every XML request entering the HTTP gateway have a unique ID (UUID) for simple identification, tracing and downstream persistence. The splitter uses some logic to split the primary XML request into smaller XMLs (each with the same UUID as its parent) and the Aggregator uses some logic to create one single XML response. Continued in the next comment

Comment: As part of this, the Correlation Strategy that I wrote makes use of the UUID for proper aggregation and it is this which is leading to the time out after the 1st successful request. Technically, yes, the intent is to ensure that every request sent by the client has a unique UUID but this is an edge case where, say, the client sends 2 requests one after the other with the same UUID, the 1st request is getting processed but for the 2nd request (and all subsequent ones), the aggregation is probably trying to correlate with UUIDs from the earlier processing, thereby leading to a timeout.

Comment: I'm not sure what the reason is for this but this is one observation from me to add to the discussion. Reason being it is working for me when I send request after request, this time, with each request having a unique UUID for the aggregator's correlation.

Comment: Answering your question Artem, strangely, I don't see any stack trace - I configured it to DEBUG as per your suggestion

Comment: @ArtemBilan The issue resurfaced (on WebSphere) where this error came from nowhere: GenericMessag W org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel send Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to a timeout:ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [productAggregator.generateAggregatedResponse.aggregator.handler]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException, headers={id=d0b52beb-e9bd-0ba2-6062-6ee83b847c4a, timestamp=1504755248824}]. Any help please?

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan - I forgot to close this question and the culprit was the UUIDs being repeated. This got solved in September 2017 after setting the DEBUG option to ON.

Comment: I think you are good to just add the answer to your own question to really close the issue. I don't see reason to remove the question.

Comment: Sure, will do that. Thanks!