# Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to a timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

This is a follow-up to this question:

[Spring Integration Aggregator failing - "No reply received within timeout" message being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987748/spring-integration-aggregator-failing-no-reply-received-within-timeout-messa)

While continuing to test my POC on WebSphere 8.5, the issue resurfaced where this error came from nowhere:

**GenericMessag W org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$‌​TemporaryReplyChanne‌​l send Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to a timeout:ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingExcept‌​ion: error occurred in message handler [productAggregator.generateAggregatedResponse.aggregator.han‌​dler]; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException, headers={id=d0b52beb-e9bd-0ba2-6062-6ee83b847c4a, timestamp=1504755248824}].**

I see that this is happening once the Aggregator has started but what is not clear is the nested exception "java.lang.NullPointerException" and what the **null** value here is that is leading to a timeout. And the other question is if the Aggregator has a default time out value to "wait" on its input channel after which it stops waiting, leading to a time out.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated while I continue to debug.

Sincerely,
Bharath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a big try/catch around your aggregator code to find out where the NPE is being thrown.

The message is generated by some up-stream messaging gateway (or direct use of a `MessagingTemplate`) where the calling thread has already timed out and this async exception is received by the template.

Comment: You have to show your `productAggregator.generateAggregatedResponse.aggregator.han‌​dler`. Looks like that is a place where NPE happens. Nothing related to the Aggregator component at all. There is just a gateway upstream of the aggregator and since there is no normal reply from your custom code because of NPE that brings us the `timeout` error.

Comment: Thanks Gary, Artem - I was able to find and fix the NPE. Now, the Aggregator is sending the aggregated message to its outputChannel (X). There is a custom-transformer that gets this message, transforms and puts it on its outputChannel (Y), which is also working perfect. The last step is for a http gateway to read from (Y) and this time, there is yet another "send Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to a timeout" message. For your note, the message on (Y) has a proper payload/headers without any NULLs - does a HTTP gateway have a default time-out w.r.t reply-channel?

Comment: The default timeout for the inbound gateway is 1000ms; you can increase it using the `reply-timeout` attribute. The timeout starts when the HTTP thread returns to the gateway; for flows that have async subflows, it's generally recommended to increase the timeout to something rather larger than the time you expect the flow to take.

Comment: Wonderful!! I set it to a higher value and it is working like a breeze :) Thanks a lot! Will keep you posted on this - highly appreciate your quick responses and valuable inputs!